# GoDaddy SMTP() Failed cPanel

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer, cpanel

After moving to a new Linux Hosting plan with cPanel (previously I had classic Linux Hosting plan with no cPanel), my old PHPMailer no longer functions. I keep getting SMTP() Failed, and in the log files, *

> "PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed
>   with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>   [file name]"

I browsed Stack Overflow for some time, and have tried a variety of solutions, be it changing a port number, host name, or SSL/TSL options, nothing seems to resolve the issue. I am rather lost, considering, previously it wasn't even necessary to specify such details. I've contacted GoDaddy's Tech Support, they've recommended using post 25 and host relay-hosting.secureserver.net, which alas, didn't make any difference.

I am using PHPMailer developed by Marcus Bointon, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

If it helps, my PHPMailer details are:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
    $mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's me! GoDaddy is a frequent pain point... They block all outbound SMTP except via their own servers. The certificate validation is due to them presenting an invalid certificate, and you're probably seeing it now because your upgrade also moved you to PHP 5.6+, which validates certificates by default. Since this is done inside GoDaddy's network, I suggest you try disabling TLS altogether:

```
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

Talking to their `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` host is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: What a privilege to receive an answer from the actual developer! Thank you for your comment, Marcus. I am afraid it hasn't affected the outcome, perhaps, my general configuration is incorrect or missing any significant details?

$mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->IsSMTP(); 
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
 $mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
 $mail->Port = 25;
 $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
 $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = false;

Comment: You're still getting a certificate verification failure after disabling TLS?? I'd recommend turning on debug output to see what's happening: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: It worked, I just had to change 'host' name to localhost, as I was getting  "Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)" error. Thank you for your help, Marcus! :)